# deno.exe running two processes, unable to stop

Tags: windows, deno

I installed deno using choco a few days back. Today my antivirus firewall gave a message that deno.exe is trying to make tcp connections to a remote ip (on Windows 10).

Taskmanager shows two deno.exe processes running which on terminating pop up right back.

I tried removing using 'choco uninstall deno' using an elevated command prompt, but it is throwing the following error -

Both deno.exe execs are in different locations -
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\deno

---- Error ----------------
choco uninstall deno
Chocolatey v0.11.3
Uninstalling the following packages:
deno

deno v1.19.0
This is try 1/3. Retrying after 300 milliseconds.
Error converted to warning:
Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\deno.exe' is denied.
This is try 2/3. Retrying after 400 milliseconds.
Error converted to warning:
Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\deno.exe' is denied.
Maximum tries of 3 reached. Throwing error.
deno not uninstalled. An error occurred during uninstall:
Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\deno.exe' is denied.

Chocolatey uninstalled 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures

- deno (exited 1) - deno not uninstalled. An error occurred during uninstall:
  Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\deno.exe' is denied.

If a package uninstall is failing and/or you've already uninstalled the
software outside of Chocolatey, you can attempt to run the command
with `-n` to skip running a chocolateyUninstall script, additionally
adding `--skip-autouninstaller` to skip an attempt to automatically
remove system-installed software. Only the packaging files are removed
and not things like software installed to Programs and Features.

If a package is failing because it is a dependency of another package
or packages, then you may first need to consider if it needs to be
removed as packages have dependencies for a reason. If
you decide that you still want to remove it, head into
`$env:ChocolateyInstall\lib` and find the package folder you want to
be removed. Then delete the folder for the package. You should use
this option only as a last resort.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the processes using Task Manager (failing that, finding the pid using [`tasklist`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist), then forcefully stopping it with [`taskkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill))?

Comment: No it cannot be stopped from the task manager or using powershell. So what i did was to uninstall deno all together.